# I am not able to connect my software with my public IP

Tags: networking, port, port-forwarding, internet, dmz

please help me in port forwarding. i m stuck in the middle.
suppose my local ip is - 192.168.0.103
and public ip is - 49.248.xx.xxx
I have D-link DSL-2520U ADSL2+ modem router
so here is what i do, i login into the router and go to the port forwarding setting and give my public ip there and port no - 4455.
I open up my software listen the port
then i go to canyouseeme.org and check my port 4455 and it dosent work.

my firewall is also off.

and As i told you i dont know much about networking so please tell me in little detail.

When i try to connect my software from my local ip. it start working but when i try to connect my software with my public ip it does not connect.

Answer (score 3):

In the port forwarding section, you should specify the *local* IP address you want to pass the packets to.

For example, if your *public* IP address is being accessed on 49.248.xxx.xxx:5901, and you have a server listening on 192.168.0.103:5901, you need a port forwarding rule for traffic to 192.168.0.103, on port 5901.

When your WAN IP address is sent a TCP or UDP packet at 5901 it will then be routed to the correct local IP address and handled by the listening server.

There are guides for your router [here](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Dlink/DSL-2520U/) which may be useful to you.

Comment: @SyedSaif Your image [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IINiP.png) shows you need a private IP of your IP: `192.168.0.103`, and all the external and internal port values of 4455. I don't know what connection to use as I don't know your configuration.

Comment: ok.. i did the same thing. in private ip column at right side i selected my local ip. on left hand side it auto selected my local ip..... protocol - all ... external start port n external end port - 4455 .... externnal start port n internal end port = 4455 ..... applied